# In jQuery, fontSize and font-size are both valid in the css() function, but in animate(), it has to be fontSize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

In jQuery, fontSize and font-size are both valid in the css() function, but in animate(), it has to be fontSize?

Are there more rules for other functions?

so the safest is still the form `fontSize`

**Update:** our project uses jQuery 1.3.1, and it will not work... but I just checked that 1.4.2 will work with "font-size" even for animate.

Comment: I'd report it as a bug: http://dev.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the .animate() API page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property. The only required parameter is a map of CSS properties. This map is similar to the one that can be sent to the .css()  method, **except that the range of properties is more restrictive.**

Comment: The next paragraph defines what they mean by "more restrictive," and it has nothing to do with aliases. It's about numeric properties.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder You are correct, after going back and looking at it, it certainly does read that way.

Answer (score 0):

in css() function if the property have "-" (such as font-size) you must use **" "** wrap it

```
$("p").css({ color: "#ff0011", background: "blue" }); 

$("p").css({ "margin-left": "10px", "background-color": "blue" });
```

in animate() function if the property have "-" you must use **CamelCase**

e.g.   marginLeft replace margin-left

Comment: All of which is true, but doesn't really relate to the questioner's question. He's clearly aware he has to put font-size in quotes. The question asks about `css` supporting font-size but `animate` not.